# Javascript Notification - maximum icon size

Tags: javascript

I am try to set and image inside desktop notification
But I didn't found what is the maximum size

I also try to look in documentation but didn't found any clarification for that

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification.

your help will be very appreciate

Comment: Than maybe there is no max size for it?

Comment: I would assume the same

Comment: The [working draft](https://notifications.spec.whatwg.org/) that specifies this feature does not say anything about a maximum icon size. The user agent may very well resize the icon to its own requirements when displaying the notification.

Comment: at least for Firefox I used a 256x256 icon which was resized to the default ~64x64, so I guess the size of the icon does not matter, it is resized

Comment: @micnic is it possible the available space for image is 39x39?
http://s10.postimg.org/cgdx14bbt/desktop_notification.png
this is what i get when notification comes

Comment: @aviram83, yes it is possible, I just approximated the size of the shown icon, in your case the area for the icon is actually 80x80 as I see, here is what I see in win8: http://i.imgur.com/RHCPwdh.png the area is 64x48 so I guess the icon is resized to 48x48, but does it really matter for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of @micnic I have found:

The size of the image will be 50% of the surface dedicated the image, based on the width.
The high will be same as the width.

It may change from one browser to another.